# Create a button that allows sending a message to the Contact of a custom Object

Tags: apex, soql, button, custom

I have a **custom Object Car__c**. One of the fields in which is **Lookup on Contact**. When I filling this fields, I must provide the ability to send a message to the **Contact** that is **selected in the current Object record**. What is the best way to choose the right solution? This is a component or a custom button or a rule. Can anybody give me some guidelines?

Comment: what do you mean with message? Is it an email? You could create a Quick Action for that.

Comment: For example I want to send some message to client who rents this car. How can I substitute a Contact Email from an record in the address field.

Comment: tell me more about your quick action method?

Comment: I am not trying to mean here, but, you may need to start saying like: **Please tell me..**. Also you have Google to look for `Salesforce Quick Action`. If you find something that is still trickier to understand after your findings, please post here like where you are stuck. We are happy to help you with that regards.

Comment: I do not see why to create an email thru Quick Action. A simple way is to create a boolean field in Car__c called 'Send Email to Contact'. Create a Process builder and test IF this field = true. If Yes, send email and set the field for false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve it with a Custom Field, a Validation Rule and a Process Builder.

1. Create a Custom Field called 'Send Email to Contact'
2. Create a validation rule that the 'Send Email to Contact could be true only when ContactID is not null
3. Create a Process builder that test the Custom Field. If it is True, send an Email to Contact and update the field to false.

I noticed that you are considering to send an email when ContactID is not null. You could also Create a Process Builder for that. Create a formula field test and check if ContactID is changed and ContactID is <> null.

Another thing that you could think if there is another field that you could use to Test. I am imagining that you are building some for a Rent Car Company. Is there a field with a Status for example that you could use?

So, There are a bunch of different approaches.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I decided to use checkbox = "true". Solution found.